# Arguments to build off snapshots vs locally compiling code?

Tags: java, maven-2, ant, continuous-integration, compilation

We have a large group of projects.  It's build using ant targets which invoke a bunch of separate maven projects.

Problem is, any time a fellow developer commits code to a separate project from the one I'm working on, I have to update the code and re-built locally in order to ensure I'm compiling against the latest.  This involves waiting between 30-60 mins every time just to test code changes.

We'd like to run all the projects off 'snapshot' jars, so each time a code change occurs, our local builds should simply download the latest snapshots.

The concern was raised that, since the continuous integration server takes over an hour to build the projects, our snapshots may be an hour behind the latest code, and building off them wouldn't be a guarentee that our code compiles against the latest.

Is this a common concern, and if so, how can it be mitigated?  Are there any good arguments that I can make to my team for the value-gained in switching to using snapshots?

Comment: I am a little concerned that you have a 30-60 minute build cycle. We use Maven to build a huge, legacy system (which use to use Ant) and our total time is around 7-10 minutes. I am guessing that your tests may be doing too much work by possibly using real, external dependencies (like a DB). You should consider addressing your long build times to get a faster feedback cycle. The whole Maven dependency problem may just go away if you try this.

Comment: This happens with the build running locally, without any DB connections.  My impression is it does this because it recompiles every single line of code in the project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making anyone who changes a component's interface also responsible for making sure that all components depending on it also still work, i.e. a single commit contains the API change, the implementation change and the changes required to make all other components build against the new version.

This encourages thinking long and hard about incompatible API changes, and also leads to explicit conflicts in the version control when committing a component that would no longer compile.

Depending on your internal policy, you can also make it acceptable to introduce new APIs and at the same time mark the old version as deprecated while still leaving the functionality intact; however I find that to be somewhat impolite towards your fellow developers.

Answer (score 0):

Is hour old code really going to be a deal breaker when making sure that code is up to date? Unless there are major changes or rewrites then I couldn't see how one change would break everything else.

I also see that your current situation is to compile all the dependencies on each build which takes about 30-60 minutes. Wouldn't it be nice to compile your project against the most recently available build, which would take I assume something like 5-10 minutes, then move on with programming?

I also don't see how a major change isn't going to be break stuff anyway. When you checkin code against an hour old build of a dependency and then that dependency changes to where it breaks your code, your code is still broken. Your now just shifting around when the fix happens.